# Block certain queries from being logged in slow query log

Tags: mysql, query, performance, slow-log

I have mysqld_node running on my mysql server to get statistics to be used by grafana + prometheus to graph dashboard for this MySQL server. However, i noticed that 90% of the queries in my slow query logs are created by mysqld_node, and hence hard to filter queries from Application servers. Is there a way to block queries from being logged in the slow query logged based on the port or some other criteria? The port for mysqld_node is 9104.

Comment: @danblack Thats not what i am trying to achieve. I want to block queries coming from a certain application e.g., app running on port 9104 to have it's queries not logged in the slow query logs regardless of their running time.

Comment: What MySQL version? Why mysql slow query log settings? There's no way mysql can know what port the app is running on. Is the mysqld_node application running on its own mysql user? What GRANTs does that user have?

Comment: 5.7. mysqld_node is running locally on the same server as the MySQL DB server. GRANT SELECT, RELOAD, PROCESS, SUPER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.*

Comment: The only way of doing a user based configuration is via init_connect, which doesn't apply to SUPER users. Changing the mysqld_node is still the best option in my experience and I'd suggest writing a bug report for it. I assume you know grafana/prometheus enough to know if there's a filtering option there.

Comment: I will just stop mysqld_node for a period of time, remove the current slow query log, then create a new one to gather queries, and finally analyze these queries minus the mysqld_node queries. Thats what i have always done. But just wanted to know if there is a way to do it without always having to stop mysqld_node.

Comment: slow query log includes the user. remove the entries for the mysqld_node user when you filter. Maybe look at [log_output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output)=TABLE for easy of filtering

Answer (score 0):

[long_query_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) is a session variable and could be set to a large value in the `mysqld_node` code.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn off `log_queries_not_using_indexes` (it's virtually useless anyway), or turn on `log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes` (if your version has such; what version are you using?).
- Use a `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to filter the slow log down to 'actionable' info.
- Cycle the slowlog.
- What is `mysql_node`?
- If mysql_node is a single user, then have it's `init_connect` turn off logging (or set `long_query_time` to a high value).  (This assumes it is not `SUPER`.)